# Easier way to create date object from string

Tags: python, datetime

I'm working on an image upload utility, and part of the functionality is to parse the IPTC and EXIF data of the images.

IPTCInfo gets the information I need, but the date fields are in the format 20130925.

Now, I can break that integer up into 2013 09 25 and create a `date` object.  Before I do so, is there already existing functionality to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that in 7986 years they're going to drag me out of cryonic retirement to fix your y10k problem? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `date` class doesn't have a string-parsing function, but the `datetime` class does, [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

So, first make a `datetime`, then extract the `date` part of it:

```
>>> s = '20130925'
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')
>>> d = dt.date()
>>> d
datetime.date(2013, 9, 25)
```

If you don't understand where the `'%Y%m%d'` comes from, see [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("20130925","%Y%m%d").date()
datetime.date(2013, 9, 25)
```

Comment: Except he asked for a `date` object, not a `datetime`.

Comment: Oops, you're right @abarnert.  I edited my answer to return a `date` object.